# Why are sequences and functions notated differently?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, soft-question, notation

Why do we usually write, e.g., $s_n$ for sequences, while functions are usually written as $f(x)$? Conceptually, aren't sequences just functions with a subset of the naturals, not of the reals, as domain?

To me, it would make more sense that the standard notation be $s(n)$, and indeed I have seen this used a few times. It also makes it easier when the argument is a complicated expression, e.g. $s\left(\frac{a^k-1}{2\pi}\right)$, which would not fit clearly in a subscript.

Comment: I don't think there's any deeper reason than just tradition.

Comment: For one thing, the notation for each arose well before the idea of "function" was generalized to include sequences.

Comment: I think that's a realization mathematicians came to before typewriters became capable of subscripts and superscripts, which is to say, before George W. Bush dodged the draft.

Comment: I don't find anything unusual if we write $s(n)$ instead of $s_{n}$ but I would strongly avoid $f_{x}$ in place of $f(x)$.